# fa icons not working on changing location

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I downloaded a template. Then i copied all folders in template to new location. On changing location a box is displayed instead of fa icons.[image] . I want to know Why fa icons are not working after changing location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add link below to your file. It will work porperly!

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [`font-awesome.css`](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css) you'll see that the paths are relative.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If you change the directory structure of your project, then it won't be able to load the font. To avoid these kinds of issues, I would recommend using the CDN for [bootstrap](http://bootstrapcdn.com/#quickstart_tab) and [font-awesome](http://bootstrapcdn.com/#fontawesome_tab) or a package manager like [Bower](http://bower.io/).

Comment: <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
I have added these two links but its still not working.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check with font-awesome.min.css file
In that file path will be given like this,
src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
check with it